# How to declare the of size of a data structure in header (C++)

Tags: c++, boost, openframeworks

I want to declare the size of my circular buffer in the header, but I don't know how. If I replace BUFFER_SIZE with a number, it will give me the error `expected a type specifier`.

ofApp.h

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{

    public:

        boost::circular_buffer<Element> cb(BUFFER_SIZE);

};
```

Comment: Have you tried `boost::circular_buffer<Element> cb{BUFFER_SIZE};` instead? Braced initialization gets around the issue of `cb` being parsed as a function returning a `circular_buffer` rather than an object of type `circular_buffer`.

Comment: Also, duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269382/unique-pointer-in-class-initialization

Comment: @NikosC. `cb{BUFFER_SIZE}` did the trick.